# Q-learning algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Good afternoon, I used q-learning to model the following problem: a set of agents have the access to 2 access points (AP) states to upload data. S={1,2} the set of states which refers to the connection to AP1 or 2. A={remain, change}. We suppose that during the total duration of simulation, the agents can access to the 2 APs. The goal is to upload the maximum of data during the simulation. The reward is a function that depends on time, which is defined as follows: R(t)= alpha*T+b, where T is the length of the interval of time and b varies over time.

In this situation, is it true to define the terminal condition as the convergence of q-tables to a pre-defined value? How the exploitation phase can be expressed (because there is not a step defined as a final goal)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In general, Q-learning is used to solve problems that can be modelled as a Markov Decision Process, which is a discrete time stochastic control process. This means that the problem has discrete intervals of time, and in a given time t, the agent is in a state s_t and has to perform an action a_t. The reward usually is a fixed function that depends on current state and action (s_t, a_t) and next state s_{t+1}. Is this your setting? What do you mean with "reward is a function that depends on time"?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reward function is defined as follows: R(t)= alpha*T+b, where T is the length of the interval of time and b varies over time

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with reward functions that depends on time. I guess you are aware of this, but the following link corresponding to a RL mailing list discussion may is useful to your problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rl-list/63PyAVuxW0o

Comment: Good morning, if we suppose that the reward doesn't depend on time. If the agents take an action periodically and we set the terminal condition as "ΔQi< epsilon" (Qi is the Q-value matrix of agent i) (i.e. we achieve the convergence of the q-learning algorithm). In this case of convergence, is it correct that each agent remains in each state until the end of the simulation ?(e.g. suppose that we have 4 agents, and the convergence is obtained when agents 1,2,3,4  have the states 1,2,1,1, respectively. they will keep the same action (i.e. remain) until the end of the simulation)

Comment: Hi again! Yes, to me it seems a reasonable assumption. If you consider the agent policy has converged, it make sense to simply let him acting according to his policy (in this case, "remain" action).

Comment: thank you sir for your help and explanation.

Comment: you are welcome :)